# jQuery the execution of my function in while does not work

Tags: jquery, arrays, function

i have a function that i want to start with different handlers.
but i can't get it right.

first i did have all the functions in separated lines.

```
$("#title_album").mouseup(function(){ menu_changer("_album") });
$("#title_animals").mouseup(function(){ menu_changer("_animals") });
$("#title_date").mouseup(function(){ menu_changer("_date") });
$("#title_nature").mouseup(function(){ menu_changer("_nature") });
$("#title_people").mouseup(function(){ menu_changer("_people") });
$("#title_place").mouseup(function(){ menu_changer("_place") });
$("#title_settings").mouseup(function(){ menu_changer("_settings") });
$("#title_stillife").mouseup(function(){ menu_changer("_stillife") });
$("#title_urban").mouseup(function(){ menu_changer("_urban") });
```

i tried to get it in a 'for' loop.

```
var menu_function_array = ["_album", "_animals", "_date", "_nature", "_people", "_place", "_settings", "_stillife", "_urban"];
for (var i = 0; i < menu_function_array.length; i = i + 1) {
    $(menu_function_array[i]).mouseup(function(){ menu_changer(menu_function_array[i]) });
}
```

now all my buttons do all the the work one the last button in the array.

how can i get this right?
Thanks in advance

Comment: How would that work, all the selectors are missing `#title`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add more jQuery (or use a closure)

```
var menu_function_array = ["_album", "_animals", "_date", "_nature", "_people", "_place", "_settings", "_stillife", "_urban"];

$.each(menu_function_array, function(_, menu_function) {
    $('#title' + menu_function).mouseup(function(){ 
        menu_changer(menu_function) 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `$.each` for your loop you will create a closure for the indexing that doesn't exist using `for`

```
$.each(menu_function_array, function(i){
    var selector='#title'+menu_function_array[i];
    $(selector).mouseup(function(){ menu_changer(menu_function_array[i]) });
});
```

Also you were missing `#title` in selector

Comment: Your answer also works, but i understand the answer of Adeneo better.
Thx for the respons! :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the code that uses a index from the loop otherwise it will take the last value of i variable;

```
var menu_function_array = ["_album", "_animals", "_date", "_nature", "_people", "_place", "_settings", "_stillife", "_urban"];
for (var i = 0; i < menu_function_array.length; i = i + 1) {
   changeMenu(i);
}

function changeMenu(index) {
   $(menu_function_array[index]).mouseup(function(){ menu_changer(menu_function_array[index])    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using one selector with [`start with selector`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/), than get the suffix by splitting the current id.

Code:

```
$("div[id^='title']").mouseup(function () {
    menu_changer("_"+$(this).attr('id').split("_")[1])
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/wfvN9/